# python import { p.* } from "./app" in typescript

Tags: python, typescript

I was wandering if there is an equivalent to this code in python `import { p.* } from "./app"` in typescript

currently I am achiving it like this but this is tedious work and it does not even work for all functions:

```js
import { p as p5 } from "./app";

const translate = p5.translate;
const rotate = p5.rotate;
const fill = p5.fill;
const strokeWeight = p5.strokeWeight;
const stroke = p5.stroke;

export { translate, rotate, fill, strokeWeight, stroke }
```

Comment: None of this is even remotely Python

Comment: `import { p.* } from "./app"` is not valid Python code.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no wildcard import feature in TypeScript (or ECMAScript).

Instead of the "tedious work" of those re-exports, you should use an editor/IDE that can deal with adding import statements, so you don't need to do it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use object destruction in export statements, so this should work, which is a bit cleaner:

```js
export const { translate, rotate, fill, stroke } from './app'
```

A cleaner option would be to have a file that has everything you want to export from it as a separate file, and use `export * from` in here instead, like so:

```js
// p.js
export { translate, rotate, ... } // use the same consts you would do in './app'
```

```js
// other.js
export * from './p'
```